# Remove bright streak from image using python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a set of images I'm using to perform a 3D reconstruction using mayavi in python, unfortunately there is a bright streak through most images over the features of interest that is screwing my reconstruction up, as shown in the figure below. The features of interest in this case are the 'holes' in the structure.

[image: Reconstruction slice with bright streak through the middle]

I've attempted to use scikit-image erode and dilate functions to remove the feature, unfortunately the distorts the rest of the image a little too much, whilst failing to remove the feature completely, as shown below.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can simply remove this bright streak, without distorting the rest of the image?

Comment: Are you interested in color information at all, or just the intervals between the notches?

Comment: maybe you can do some filtering in the frequency domain

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Sorry forgot to say, the intensities correspond to image gray-scale intensities. I've plotted them here using matplotlib's plasma colour scheme for clarity but I'm interested only in the shape of the notches.

Comment: If you are only interested in the shapes, why is the streak problematic?